# how to enqueu customiser/customizer scripts?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, theme-customizer

my script has one line `wp.customize.control('control_id').deactivate()`
the control DOES exist. as an evidence I inject the above code directly into the browser consol and it works (the control dissapears).
this is what I tried so far in `functions.php`:

```
add_action('customize_controls_enqueue_scripts',function(){
    wp_enqueue_script('customize_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/customize.js', ['customize-controls'],false,true);
},999);
```

`customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` hook is the only one that makes sense to be used.
`customize-controls` is also the only dependency I could think of (an invalid dependency name will result into the script not being enqueued).
I also have the last boolean set to `True` to make sure the script is putted in the end.
and the last parameter `999` to make sure it's the last script to be added.
YET I keep getting in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'deactivate' of undefined`
I wait a second and inject the code directly in the console and it works.
anyone has an idea how to acheive a simple task that was not covered in the [theme development handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/) ?

Answer (score 1):

after some research found that:

```
wp.customize.bind("ready", function () {});
```

is how to wrap the code properly to make sure everything is loaded before writing any algorithm